# SQLSTATE[42S22]:Column not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have create Formtype UniversitaireType but I have this error:

[image]

attribut condidat_id doesn't create in database when I try command php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force (all attributs create in database except id_condidat) .. I make mapping OneToMany $condidat in entity Universitaire

code entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Condidat;

/**
 * Universitaire.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="universitaires")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UniversitaireEntityRepository")
 */
class Universitaire
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_start", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateStart;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_end", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateEnd;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="establishment", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $establishment;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="diploma", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $diploma;

    /**
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Condidat",mappedBy="id_universitaire",cascade={"persist"})
     *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_condidat", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $condidat;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add Condidat
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Condidat $condidat
     * @return Universitaire
     */
    public function addCondidat(\AppBundle\Entity\Condidat $condidat)
    {
        $this->condidat[] = $condidat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove Condidat
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Condidat $condidat
     */
    public function removeCondidat(\AppBundle\Entity\Condidat $condidat)
    {
        $this->Condidat->removeElement($condidat);
    }

    /**
     * Get Condidat
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCondidat()
    {
        return $this->condidat;
    }


    /**
     * Set dateStart.
     *
     * @param string $dateStart
     *
     * @return Universitaire
     */
    public function setdateStart($dateStart)
    {
        $this->dateStart = $dateStart;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateStart.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getdateStart()
    {
        return $this->dateStart;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateEnd.
     *
     * @param string $dateEnd
     *
     * @return Universitaire
     */
    public function setDateEnd($dateEnd)
    {
        $this->dateEnd = $dateEnd;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateEnd.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getdateEnd()
    {
        return $this->dateEnd;
    }

    /**
     * Set establishment.
     *
     * @param string $establishment
     *
     * @return Universitaire
     */
    public function setEstablishment($establishment)
    {
        $this->establishment = $establishment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get establishment.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEstablishment()
    {
        return $this->establishment;
    }

    /**
     * Set diploma.
     *
     * @param string $diploma
     *
     * @return Universitaire
     */
    public function setDiploma($diploma)
    {
        $this->diploma = $diploma;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get diploma.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDiploma()
    {
        return $this->diploma;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ResponsableCategory = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    }
```

code FormType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Entity\Universitaire;
use AppBundle\Entity\Condidat;

class UniversitaireType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('dateStart')->add('dateEnd')->add('establishment')->add('diploma')
            ->add('condidat',null, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Condidat',
        'choice_label' => 'condidat',));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Universitaire',
            "csrf_protection" => "false"
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_universitaire';
    }


}
```

Comment: As it seems, the Column "f0_.username" doesn't exist. Check the structure of the table "f0_" in your database.

Comment: Post entity definition for AppBundle\Entity\Condidat

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your "condidat" property.

1. You used One-To-Many (Bidirectional). If you want to have only one 
   candidate per "Universitaire" - then you have to use One-To-One (Bidirectional).

   ```
   class Universitaire
   {

       ## ...

       /**
        * Bidirectional One-To-One (Owning Side)
        * 
        * @ORM\OneToOne(
        *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Condidat",
        *     inversedBy="universitaire",
        *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}
        *     )
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(
        *     name="condiat_id", 
        *     referencedColumnName="id"
        *     )
        */
        private $condidat;

   class Condidat
   {

       ## ...

       /**
        * Bidirectional One-To-One (Inversed Side)
        * 
        * @ORM\OneToOne(
        *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Universitaire",
        *     mappedBy="condidat",
        *     )
        */
        private $universitaire;
   ```
2. If not, and One-To-Many was exactly you wanted to have, than you have to set in your `__construct()` that "condidat" is an array collection

   ```
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->condidat = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
   }
   ```

   If I were you I'd rather use "candidates" with "s" - to show, that this an arrayCollection.
3. As I've already said - your example is Bidirectional One-To-Many. In this case we use mappedBy and inversedBy. Entity, in which you set Join column is Owning side. And of course JoinColumn has to be in the "Candidate" entity. So:

   ```
   class Universitaire
   {

       ## ...

       /**
        * Bidirectional One-To-Many (Owning Side)
        * Predicate: One Universitaire can have a lot of candidates
        * 
        * @ORM\OneToMany(
        *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Condidat",
        *     mappedBy="universitaire",
        *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}
        *     )
        */
        private $condidats;

   class Condidat
   {

       ## ...

       /**
        * Bidirectional Many-To-One (Owning Side)
        * Predicate: Each Condidat belongs to one Universitaire
        * 
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(
        *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Universitaire",
        *     inversedBy="condidats",
        *     )
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(
        *     name="universitaire_id",
        *     referencedColumnName="id", 
        *     onDelete="SET NULL"
        *      )
        */
        private $universitaire;
   ```

I added `onDelete="SET NULL"`. If you delete universitaire then in field universitaire of each "condidate" you will see null value.